# Applescript - Close all windows except frontmost window

Tags: applescript, automator, catalina

I have created an automator quick action that runs the following apple script

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true --retrieves name of open application
end tell

tell application frontApp
    repeat while window 2 exists
        close window 2
    end repeat
end tell
```

It works; however, it takes a while to run if I have a lot of windows open.

Is there a way to close all windows **simultaneously** except for the frontmost one?

I typed in `tell application "Finder" to close every window from 2 to 5`
After I compiled it, it automatically changed to `tell application "Finder" to close ( windows 2 thru 5 )`. However, I get the error message `error "Finder got an error: Can’t get windows 2 thru 3." number -1728 from windows 2 thru 3`. So, then, it accepts the structure of the command, but I'm still missing something.

**Edit**: I tried the following script

```
tell application "Finder"
    close (every window where index is greater than 1)
end tell
```

However, I get the error `"Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class." number -10010`

Why does this not work?

Comment: @user3439894 Sorry, I entered the code in wrong. I have now changed `tell application "Finder"` to `tell application frontApp`. This code is meant to be run as an Automator service. It has to first retrieve the name of the frontmost application because it needs to be able to run for any application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. It might run faster. (edited my original answer with new code).

```
tell application "Finder"

    set theWindows to {}
    set theCount to (count of windows)
    if theCount is greater than 1 then
        repeat with i from 2 to theCount
            set theWindow to window i
            copy theWindow to end of theWindows
        end repeat
        close theWindows
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: It works, although it is just as slow as the original version. I'm still looking for a faster method.

Comment: @PeterSchorn I edited my answer with new code. Please try that.

Comment: It worked. You're a god damn genius.

Comment: Oh, wait. I spoke too soon. This only works with Finder. If I try it with another application, I get `[Application] got an error: Can’t make {window id 39921, window id 39922} into type specifier.` I think the problem is that the script is referring to the windows by their ID, rather than by their index.

Comment: Honestly, I'm just being too picky by expecting it to be fast. The other version works just fine.

Comment: @PeterSchorn So you want something that will go through every application and close everything except window #1 for each application? Or you just want the current application to close every window except the first one?

Comment: @PeterSchorn You could try replacing 
``tell application "Finder"``
with 
``tell current application``
which will always choose the front application. The code I wrote might only work on the Finder, but it is worth trying on your end.

Comment: I want the current application to close every window except the one in the front. I've already figured out how to retrieve the name of the front application and pass it into the next part of the code—that's what the first tell block of the code at the very top of my question does.

Comment: Your code does EXACTLY what I want—except it only worked with the Finder application. Have you tried it with other applications to see if you get the same error I mentioned in a comment above? By the way, I really appreciate all the effort you're putting into this.

Comment: Also, I may need to run the script as its _own_ application. Do you know how I can get the name of the frontmost application other than the script I'm currently running?

Comment: @PeterSchorn as soon as you run the script as an app, it will always become the front application. You should probably research something like how to make an Automator Service into a Keyboard Shortcut. This way you could run the script while the frontmost application remains in front. An easier way to accomplish this would be with a Better Touch Tool (Commercial Product, $7.50 for a two year license, with a 45 day free trial. Cheap but a little bit of a learning curve) or Keyboard Maestro (Commercial Product, $36 for a license, free 30 day trial. More expensive, but easier to pick up IMHO)

Comment: Both Better Touch Tool and Keyboard Maestro allow you to create keyboard shortcuts that will then launch an AppleScript without making it the front application.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions; I'll have to check out those third-party applications. However, is there a way to get the name of the application that is the second from the front? Also, have you been able to figure out why your code only works for "Finder"? Is it because other applications aren't scriptable or have different syntax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101849/discussion-between-chris-norman-and-peter-schorn).

Answer (score 5):

If you're running it as an *Automator* **quick action**, then you can close all windows except the frontmost window of the frontmost application by using the code below inside a **Run AppleScript** action (you can delete any sample code that appears, including `on run {input, parameters}...end run`:

```
tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents" to tell the first process ¬
    whose frontmost = true to tell a reference to windows 2 thru -1 to ¬
    if exists then tell the value of attribute "AXCloseButton" to click
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: All solutions which use one tell to `System Events` to get the name of the frontmost app and then another tell to the frontmost application by explicit name as determined have a big downside since the increased automation security introduced in macOS Catalina:

For each app where you trigger your quick action you must give permission that app X can control System Events:  Privacy > Automation > App XXX [√] System Events, App YYY [√] System Events, etc…

Sadly the seemingly intuitive `tell frontmost application` inside an AppleScript inside a Quick Action is not supported. Any solutions?

Comment: @porg That's why one shouldn't use _System Events_ to get the frontmost application if all you need is the frontmost application. It's used here because _System Events_ would be needed for any AppleScript solution to work on applications that aren't scriptable.  If one knows in advance that the application ***is*** scriptable, then do this: `tell the app named (path to frontmost application) to tell ref windows 2 thru -1 to if exists then close`

Comment: @CJK thx for the explanation! My AppleScript throws a dialog to resize the frontmost window in the frontmost app with `set the bounds of the front window to {x1, y1, x1 + xInputEvaluated, y1 + yInpEvaluated}`. Apps which fail with `Can’t get bounds of window 1` (cross-platform apps like LossLessCut, Visual Studio Code, qView) or even more rudimentary with `Can’t get window 1.` (e.g. ImageOptim) fail anyhow, regardless whether telling them directly or via System Events. Changed my Quick Action AppleScript accordingly. Removed apps' permissions to control System Events at Privacy > Automation.

Comment: @porg I'll clarify what I wrote in my previous comment, as it seems you're working off half the information. Applications are either AppleScriptable (aka. "scriptable"), or they aren't. An app that ***is*** scriptable can be controlled natively with AppleScript, which for what we're talking about, means `window 1` will be a defined object, and it will have a property called `bounds` allowing changing of window size/position. For all other apps, `window` is not defined, hence `bounds` will also not be defined. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ However, AppleScript provides a way to interface with accessibility hooks exposed by an application that provide access to information about graphical elements that are used to create a visual interface for the user to interact with the app. Such elements include the menu bar, window frames, window contents (like buttons, text, images, etc.), but they have to be elements native to a macOS environment. So content rendered by HTML will not be detected, nor will apps that use systems like Java to create interfaces independent of the OS it runs on. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ AppleScript calls out to _System Events_ in order to hook into the Graphical User Interface of a specific running process. The `process` class is the AppleScript object used to interface with the app running inside the process. A `process` class object for a specific app will enumerate any and all (G)UI elements that are native to macOS and not intentionally obfuscated by developers, plus non-native elements that _are_ purposely exposed by developers for accessibility.  `window` objects are top-level UI elements, so are owned directly by the containing `process` object. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ **NOTE:** a `window` object belonging to a scriptable application's AppleScript object hierarchy is ***not*** the same as the `window` object belonging to a _System Events_ `process`, so they each have their own defined list of properties, of which `bounds` is only defined for scriptable windows. UI window elements hold the information about the window's frame in two separate `size` and `position` properties. All scriptable apps can also have their windows manipulated through UI hooks, so for window manipulation in the general case, you have to use _System Events_. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ Apple's security impositions are applicable whichever way you attempt to control an application, be it via a _System Events_ process hook, or native AppleScriptability. You just have to grin and bare it for the first of each authorisation request, after which, it won't ask again for the same script/app pairings.  For your script, you need to remove all code blocks that `tell application <app>` for anything other than `<app>` being `"System Events"` (or equivalent `id` reference).  `set the bounds...` no longer applies. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ You want something along the lines of this: `tell app "System Events" to tell the first process whose frontmost = true to tell ref window 1 to if it exists then set its [position,size] to [[x1, y1],[xInputEvaluated, yInputEvaluated]]`.  This will work for the vast majority of apps, except the rare few. Of your list, only _LossLessCut_ generates its own non-native interface; the rest will all respond to _System Events_'s access control. _Fin._ ☐

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect this to work for every app but it should for any scriptable app. NB Some apps have invisible windows (e.g. omnioutliner has various 'license' windows) so I've added a filtre to only include 'visible' windows. Perhaps that will cause the script to break on some apps. I've tested it on the Finder and OO.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell

tell application frontApp
    
    set ab to windows whose visible is true
    set bc to rest of ab
    
    try
        close bc
    on error
        repeat with y in bc
            close y
        end repeat
    end try
    
end tell
```

In general, the frontmost window has an index of 1. So this script makes a list of visible windows and then uses the 'rest' command to make a second list of every item after the first from list 1 (i.e. not window 1).

Awkwardly, different applications implement 'close' differently. With the Finder you can close a list of windows, with OO you cannot — it generates a -1700 error. So the last part of the script tries to close the list of windows and if that generates an error, it cycles through the list, closing each window sequentially.